# How do I create popup with data user enters into a form?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, asp.net-core

```
<!--Currently making web app that is a bunch of forms.
```

I created using Visual Studio 2017 ASP.NET Core 2.2 with Angular 7.
When user fills out form not all form data is required. 
After user enters desired form information I want there to be a button that brings up a popup that contains all user entered data and corresponding questions. 
If they leave a textbox on the form blank or enter n/a I do not want the information to appear in the popup. 
I want the popup to have a button to copy data that will be pasted into form on another site.

```
I have created all my forms and also know how to create a popup.
```

My only issue is I have no idea how to populate/transfer user entered information from form into the popup and excluding the text boxes not filled out by user.-->

```
<!-- this is th .html -->

<form [formGroup]="Form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

    <div class="form-row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-auto">
            <br />
//
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Select1">Select your...</label>
                <select class="form-control" formControlName="Select1">
                    <option>...</option>
                    <option>...</option>
                    <option>Other</option>

                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Number">some info </label>
                <textarea class="form-control" formControlName="Number" rows="1" placeholder="Separate case numbers by comma"></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Purpose">Purpose of info: </label>
                <textarea class="form-control" formControlName="Purpose" rows="1"></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name of info: </label>
                <textarea class="form-control" formControlName="name" rows="1"></textarea>
            </div>

            <


        </div>

    </div>

    <p>
        Form Value: {{ Form.value | json }}
    </p>
    <p>
        Form Status: {{ Form.status }}
    </p>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" [disabled]="!labForm.valid">Build Lab Request</button>

    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Template</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title text-left">Lab Access Template</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Want user entered form data to appear on popup.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Copy Template</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</form>

<!--this is the .ts-->
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, Validator, FormGroup, Validators, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-',
    templateUrl: './.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./.component.scss']
})
/**  component*/
export class Component {



    Form = new FormGroup({
        Select1: new FormControl(''),
        Number: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        Purpose: new FormControl(''),
        name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),

    });



    onSubmit() {
        console.warn(this.labForm.value);
    }


    /** LabAccess ctor */
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }



}
```

Comment: This is more of a javascript question than a css question. Javascript will probably be your best route for such a task.

Comment: hum... How do you create your popup ? Angular Material Dialog ? I will say you just have to pass the data to your dialog component instance but as I don't know how it's looks like, it's difficult to answer more precisely. Can you provide a stackblitz, I will take a look :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're attempting to do is pretty straightforward, and you've got a lot of things already in place (like reactive forms) to make it happen.

Your modal you've got is fine, but you probably ought to use a separate component for the popup, and to pass information to it, it would look like this:

Within your calling template, include some template that will have a template for the popup or modal or whatever, which contains the component, see below:

```html
<ng-template #formPopup>
    <form-popup
        [select1]="Form.get( 'Select1' ).value"
        [number]="Form.get( 'Number' ).value"
        [purpose]="Form.get( 'Purpose' ).value"
        [name]="Form.get( 'name' ).value">
    </form-popup>
</ng-template>
```

This will pass these values in as inputs as they are into your component when it's created:

```js
export class FormPopupComponent {
    @Input() select1 : any;
    @Input() number : number;
    @Input() purpose : string;
    @Input() name : string;

    // Do things with these inputs as needed in this component
}
```

On click, as you pointed out, you'll also have to open your dialog or popup or whatever, which is described [in detail here](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview). But here's a quick summary - in your component for your original form-containing template, you'll need a reference to your popup, which we've already created:

```js
@ViewChild( 'formPopup' ) formPopupRef : TemplateRef<any>;

constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

    openDialog(): void {
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open( this.formPopupRef );
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this.